# How to combine indirect and direct references in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sum, excel-indirect

Issue: 
I need to call direct and indirect references. I have a column that shifts to the right every time the program is run. The column is being used to collect the sum of the preceding columns.  (I'm aware I can combine the sheet1 within the with, however there are pieces of code between the with and sheet select and this particular question focuses on just the .value section.)

Code 1:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
With Range("AL2")
.Value = "=SUM(B2:RC[-1])"
End With
```

B2 is being inserted as a string, instead of as a cell name.

I've also tried:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
With Range("AL2")
.Value = "=SUM(range("B2") & ":RC[-1])"
End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
With Range("AL2")
.Value = "=SUM("& B2 & ":RC[-1])"
End With
```

This particular set of code does not run correctly and returns:

> SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Why not `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AL2").Formula = "=SUM(B2:AK2)"`

Comment: The code adds in a new column each time it is run, and there is code between the sheet select and the latter code, but I condensed it to show in the question.

Answer (score 3):

So, the problem in this specific instance is that you are mixing R1C1 and A1 style notation.

Anyway, I'd change your code to set the .Formula property instead of the .Value property, and specifically change it to .FormulaR1C1 if you want to use that notation or leave it as .Formula for A1 notation.

Anyway, your original code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
With Range("AL2")
    .Value = "=SUM(B2:RC[-1])"
End With
```

This is setting B2 as a string because Excel is recognizing the RC notation, correctly interpreting that "RC[-1]" is a cell reference, but then not understanding what "B2" means.

So, I'd use something like this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AL2")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C2:RC[-1])"
End With
```

That however would leave $B$2 as an absolute cell reference, and AK2 as a relative reference, which is kind of gross. Depending on your needs you could do this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AL2")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C2:R2C37)"
End With
```

Which would lead to both being absolute references.

If you want something more dynamic, you'll need to use string manipulation on the string you're inputting into the worksheet. For instance, if you have r1 as a range object (with address B2) and r2 as a range object (with address AK2), you could do this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AL2")
    .Formula = "=SUM(" & r1.address ":" & r2.address & ")"
End With
```

If you have questions, let me know.